# How to swipe back from a page pushed from side menu in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating an ionic app. I would push a page directly from my side menu. When i pushing it, i can't turn back with swipe but only with back arrow. 
How i can fix this?
I tried to remove lazy loading but never change.
Thanks.

This is my code in menu.ts:

```
openPage(page: PageInterface){
let params = {};

if(page.index){
  params = {tabIndex: page.index};
}

console.log(this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0]);

if(this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0] && page.index != undefined){
  this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0].select(page.index);
}else{
  this.nav.push(page.pageName);
}
}
```

Comment: Hello! Please provide and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu" ></ion-icon>
      </button>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-header>
```

Add this in your page html. Hope this work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work again. When i try to swipe back, it opens a side menu instead to go back.

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-swipe-between-pages-in-ionic/99833

This might help.